# How do I change the salt used for the user password when creating an account?

Tags: 8, users

I am working on Drupal 8 site where the client has asked us to use their own custom salt when storing the user password in the database.

Is it possible to set a custom salt for a Drupal site?

The client is thinking of the feature from a security perspective. What can be done?

Comment: You can set the hash salt in settings.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `site/default/settings.php`  there is a config for salt

`$settings['hash_salt']`,  passwords are hashed with this salt. you can change it to whatever the client has asked you.